# Move photos to photo folder retrospectively

Tags: qgis

I have a project that I have taken a number of photos which are saved in the project folder. If I create a sub photo folder and move the photos into the new folder (after setting the layer photos attributes to @project-folder '/photos' etc), can I tell the project how to find the photos in the new location

---

When I set up my project I set the photos attribute to save images in the 'Relative project path', which means they were saved in the primary folder. I have modified the setting using the @project-folder '/photos' method to save the image files in a sub-folder named /photos. Now, any new photo go into the /photos folder and are able to be displayed when inspecting a point.

I have moved the previous image files to the /photos sub-folder hoping they would be found and displayed when inspect a point, but they are not displayed.

So what can I do to have the project will find the old images as well as the new in the photo folder and display them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do you currently "tell the project how to find the photos"? i.e., are you displaying them somewhere as point raster symbology or in an attributes form?

Comment: Are you using QField?

Comment: Also, Hello and welcome to GIS.SE! Please find a moment to take a look at the tour ( https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour ) to make yourself familiar with the site and its functions.

Comment: After taking some photos I changed the photos path attribute to @project-folder '/photos' and moved images to the photo folder. The images are no longer displayed. Is there a way to have the moved images detected and display?